# Trigger input onChange event programmatically in react input element

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a number of buttons that I want to click and set the value of an input filed based on those buttons values. I'm using react hook form with onChange as the mode but because the input is not getting the onChange event I want to be able to triigger the inputs onChange event programmatically so react hook form gets updated via its onChange mode.

In the example below when I call the onManualChange and pass it a value it does not dispatch the input onChange event ?
current below is a reference to the react input element.

```
  const {
    register,
    setValue,
  } = useForm({
    mode: 'onChange',
  })


   const onManualChange= (value: number) => {
      const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true })
      setValue(current.name, value))
      current?.dispatchEvent(event)
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses synthetic events, which you cannot emit using `dispatch`. As far as I know they don't expose an API to emit them programatically. You can just add a native listener instead of using React's events. You could make a little hook for it:

```js
/** @returns [ref object, event emitter] */
export default function useEvent<T extends HTMLElement>(
  name: string,
  callback: (e: Event) => any
): [MutableRefObject<T | null>, () => void] {
  const ref = useRef<T | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current?.addEventListener(name, callback);
    return () => ref.current?.removeEventListener(name, callback);
  }, [ref.current, name, callback]);
  
  return [ref, () => ref.current?.dispatchEvent(new Event(name))];
}
```

Usage:

```
  const [inputRef, emitEvent] = useEvent<HTMLInputElement>('customEvent', (e) =>
    console.log('Event fired', e, e.target)
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={emitEvent}>EMIT</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ay2m4z?file=App.tsx

Comment: I get this error in typescript for when returning ref:  Type 'MutableRefObject<T | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<T>'.
  Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | undefined'.

Comment: Yeah typescript strict mode will catch that - the ref is undefined at first so you should check for it. I edited my answer to instantiate the ref as null. I made it so nothing happens if the ref is still null, ie. you forgot to attach it to an element - you could throw an error to let yourself know instead.